# SwiftUI: .fileImporter modifier not updating binding when dismissed by tapping "outside" the file picker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using the ".fileImporter" modifier in a SwiftUI view; it works great, except for one very annoying issue that I have not been able to find a solution for anywhere.

The "picker", which is bound to a state variable `showFileImporter` as required by the documentation (initially set to false), and configured to allow multiple selection, is presented by "toggling" the state variable when the user taps a button. Up to this point, all is good: the picker presents, I can effectively pick files (and get the corresponding URLs collection `onCompletion`), which in turn dismisses the picker view and sets the bound state variable `showFileImporter` back to `false`, as it should.
Also, if after presenting the picker the user taps the Cancel button on the view UI, the picker is appropriately dismissed and the bound variable set to `false`- again, as it should.

**The issue comes when you dismiss the picker by tapping outside the picker view.**

The picker gets dismissed, alright, BUT the bound variable DOES NOT get updated - thus, in my case, the user has to tap the "pick files" button twice in order for the picker to preset itself, obviously because when dismissed in this way the value of the `showFileImporter` state variable is not updated and the toggle action on it triggered by tapping the button will set it to `false` "first", and then to `true` on the second tap, which then triggers the picker presentation.

Anyone has any idea if this is a bug? Am I doing something inherently wrong, or missing something? Just for completion, I am including a sample code that exhibits this behaviour:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showFileImporter: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Pick Some Files...") {
                showFileImporter.toggle()                
            }
        }
        .fileImporter(
            isPresented: $showFileImporter, 
            allowedContentTypes: [.video, .audio, .image], 
            allowsMultipleSelection: true, 
            onCompletion: { result in
                /* ...some code here */
        })
        
    }
}
```

Any pointers, hints or help at all is greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems like a bug. You should submit a report to Apple. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: That's what I thought also. I have submitted a report, but my hopes are not that high with that... thanks for your comment nonetheless.

Comment: Work around provided in a duplicate question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69757562/265940

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI .fileImporter cannot show again after dismissing by swipe down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613669/swiftui-fileimporter-cannot-show-again-after-dismissing-by-swipe-down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a certified bug (confirmed by Apple). Hopefully will be solved soon.

Comment: Feb 22, still broken.

Comment: wait wwdc 2022 ______